# How can I prove that $\{ \ (x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 : x >0, 0\le y \le 1/x \ \} \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R^2)$ is a Borel-set in $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

How can I prove that $\{ \ (x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 : x >0, 0\le y \le 1/x \ \}  \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R^2)$ is a Borel-set in $\mathbb R^2$ ?

I have tried to construct this set from countably union of sets in $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^2)$ ($(a,b) \times (c,d), (-\infty,b] \times (-\infty, c]$ and the like), but without success.

Now, I'm pretty stuck and advice on the subject is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The functions $f(x,y)=x$, $g(x,y)=y$, $h(x,y)=1/x-y$ (in the last one $x\not=0$) are Borel measurable (they are continuous). Can you write your set using inverse images of these functions?

Comment: I guess I should write $f^{-1}((0,1])$ and then take intersection ? Can you help with the other two ? (and afterwards take unions)

Comment: Your set equals $f^{-1}((0,\infty))\cap g^{-1}([0,\infty))\cap h^{-1}([0,\infty))$.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out myself :), however, I need $h$ to be a function $R^2 \rightarrow R$ in order to use this theorem saying that $h$ is $B(R^2)-B(R)$ measurable ? This condition is not satisfied here :/ ? In fact $h$ is a function $R^2 / \{(0,y) : y \in R\} \rightarrow R$ ?

Comment: Its fine, let the domain of $h$ be $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{x>0\}$ in which your set is contained anyway.

Comment: But then $h$ is not continuous in $(0,0)$ ?

Comment: Is $(0,0)$ in the domain? No.

Comment: You know, if $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and you have a set $B\subset A$ measurable in $A$ (considered as a measure space by itself inheriting the measure space structure), then it is also measurable in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Ahh so we consider $f,g,h$ to be functions from $x>0, 0\le y\le 1/x$ to $R$. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for a given $x>0$ you can find that 
$$ \{ (x,y); 0<= y< = 1/x \}$$
is a Borel set and proceed from there?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\{x>0, 0 \leq y \leq 1/x\}$,  $B=\{x,y; x\geq 0, y\geq 0, xy \leq 1\}$, $C=\{x=0, y\geq 0\}$. We have $A=B\cap {}^c C$. As $B$ and $C$ are clearly closed sets, they are Borel, hence ${}^c C$ is Borel, and also $A$.